# Intellij. How to prevent terminal tabs from closing?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have grown quite comfortable with having a set of terminal tabs in Intellij, in which I have separate command histories and stuff.

But from time to time I happen to close one of them, loosing it's history.

Is there a way to pin them or atleast have a confirmation for closing it?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please vote for the related requests on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215687, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214624

Comment: Thanks for the input